# A locally injection is an injection?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a (path-)connected space, and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous mapping, if for any $x\in X$, there exist a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, such that $f$ is an injection on $U$, then $f$ is an injection (on $X$).

Is this right?

Or we need strength the conditon of $X$?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Consider $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$ defined by $(x,y)\to e^x(\cos(y),\sin(y))$. Its jacobian never vanishes, so $f$ is a local diffeomorphism (in particular, it's locally injective), but it's not globally injective.